# Issue in Jenkins slave is failed to connect Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 servers lets say A and B
My Jenkins is running on Server A and Jenkins Slave Agent is running on Server B.

In Server A java version is "jre1.8.0_171" and On server B it is "jre1.8.0_201" (previously it was "jre1.8.0_72" on server B).

Now When I try to run below command :
"javaws http://uksc-solcaraqa:8080/computer/uksc-bpro/slave-agent.jnlp" it give below error "Trying Protocol:JNLP2 connect".  Previously it was working fine and also able to connect.

[image]

Because of it one of my Jenkins job is not able to start as My server B is offline.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't mention your Jenkins version, but JNLP2 has long since been [deprecated](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/08/11/remoting-update/). It is not secure. [Changlog](https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/) says it was disabled inJenkins LTS 2.89.1 - 2017-12-06 (latest is 2.204.2).

Comment: I am using Jenkins version "1.647"

Comment: That's gonna tough to figure out. No doubt there's a security update  in Java btwn 1.8 72 and 201 that is preventing it from launching/connecting. Jenkins(https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/) now offers Node monitoring (https://plugins.jenkins.io/versioncolumn/) to detect compatibility issues, but they probably won't work on your version. You might just have to bite the bullet and u/g to Jenkins 2.x. You should probably do that for stability, security and functionality anyway.

Comment: Thans @IanW for response